# form_tag, controller, action not redirecting to posts/index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

this should be easy, but I am not sure why it does not work. I have a search form in the nav bar. When I conduct search in the navbar in posts/index, I can get search results with no problem. As shown below:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=✓&query=technology
```

However, when I go to posts/show and conduct a search, the search does not redirect me to posts/index to provide results. Instead I get the below.

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/history?utf8=✓&query=technology.
```

The output from pry.

```
[1] pry(#<CategoriesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"technology", "controller"=>"categories", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"history"}
```

Code is as below:

Views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "posts", :action => "index"}, method: :get) do %>        
<div class="form-group">
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search Here" %>
</div>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts 
resources :categories
```

Thanks in advance.

#### UPDATE 1

1) Adding picture from Safari inspect element
[image]

2) I also made a mistake by saying that "...when I go to posts/show and conduct..." it should be "...when I go to categories/show and conduct..."

#### UPDATE 2

Per request from the comment, here are some additional information for consideration.

Views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb

```
  <li>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <%= form_tag({:controller => "posts", :action => "index"}, method: :get) do %>        
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search This Page" %>
    </div>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>        
  </form>
  </li>
```

views/categories/show.html.erb

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <% @category.each do |post| %>
      <%= render 'posts/post', post: post %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @category %>
```

views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= render 'post', post: post %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Also, please find additional screenshots of posts/index and categories/show attached below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you inspect the generated form from `posts/show` with firebug or something and post it here?

Comment: @hakcho, thanks for the reply. I have added a picture of the search form's Safari inspect element result. I also made a mistake it is categories/show not posts/show. Can refer to the updates. Thank you.

Comment: From the screenshot I can tell you this is not the form you have defined in `_navigation.html.erb`. If you look closely you will see that the placeholders are not the same. The placeholder from the template says  `Search here` but the page's form says `Search This Page`.

Comment: Yes, I made the change from "this page" to "here" when submitting this post. Why I did that? I thought maybe it looked better in the form. the rest are the same.

Comment: Can you add the template for the view you are visiting because I still have the filling this form is not exactly the same?

Comment: @hakcho, I am grateful that you are really taking the time and effort to help me with this. Although I can't say I understand your requirements entirely, I have added more screenshots and information for your reference.

Comment: The problem is simple. Your form does not have `action` attribute which should be generated by `{ :action ... }`. When there is no such attribute the form is submited with action equal to the current page url. That is why your search works in post view but not in categories. The real problem is why `form_tag` does not generate action attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "posts", :action => "index"}, method: :get) do
```

`form_tag` will generate `<form>` element for you. Now you have nesting of form elements and the top one is considered to be the form. Remove `<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">` and add to `form_tag` `:class => 'navbar-form navbar-left'` as another option.

Comment: I would like to have found this answer 4 hours ago. Thanks